# responsiveslides.js - auto not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I am using this script to add responsive slideshows to a little website. I have not found a perfect slideshow script yet, and I doubt it exists. I have come from owl-slider, flux-slider to jquery basic slider, and now I have arrived at responsiveslides.js (responsiveslides.com / https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js)

My Problem is, that I cannot get the auto-setting to work. This is my code to fire the plugin:

```
$(".rslides_home").responsiveSlides({
    'pause':true
});
```

This setting should stop the animation, I only want it to slide per click. But it doesnt do a thing. Changing the default settings does the job though.

Has anyone an Idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong option. "Pause" has a different meaning in the slider.
Auto-option defines if the slider is autoplaying.

```
  $(".rslides_home").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false
    });
```

Here are the defined options for the slider. As you can see, the "pause" option is used when you want the slider to stop when hovered.

```
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  timeout: 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  pager: false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  nav: false,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  pause: false,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  navContainer: "",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
  manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
  before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
  after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
});
```

These options are taken from http://responsiveslides.com/

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?